# Sorting with $year

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this data in my "consumption" collection of a database.
It tells how much 'volume' of water is consumed between 'startTime' and 'endTime'

```
{ "startTime" : ISODate("2014-09-01T00:30:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2014-09-01T00:40:00Z"), "volume" : 5 }
{ "startTime" : ISODate("2014-09-01T02:30:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2014-09-01T19:00:00Z"), "volume" : 10.2 }
{ "startTime" : ISODate("2014-09-01T10:45:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2014-09-01T11:00:00Z"), "volume" : 8.2 }
{ "startTime" : ISODate("2014-09-04T01:00:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2014-09-04T01:15:00Z"), "volume" : 20.3 }
{ "startTime" : ISODate("2014-09-04T04:45:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2014-09-04T07:50:00Z"), "volume" : 15 }
{ "startTime" : ISODate("2014-09-04T14:30:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2014-09-04T14:35:00Z"), "volume" : 0.8 }
{ "startTime" : ISODate("2014-09-07T04:30:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2014-09-07T05:45:00Z"), "volume" : 5 }
{ "startTime" : ISODate("2014-09-08T08:00:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2014-09-08T08:02:00Z"), "volume" : 0.2 }
{ "startTime" : ISODate("2014-09-08T08:05:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2014-09-08T08:08:00Z"), "volume" : 1 }
{ "startTime" : ISODate("2014-09-08T15:30:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2014-09-08T16:00:00Z"), "volume" : 3 }
{ "startTime" : ISODate("2014-09-11T00:00:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2014-09-11T00:30:00Z"), "volume" : 10.5 }
```

I want to group the data by year and get the total volume by year.

```
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2012 }, "Total" : 5 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2011 }, "Total" : 40 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2010 }, "Total" : 10 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2013 }, "Total" : 30.5 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2014 }, "Total" : 484.04999999999995 }
```

I am able to achieve this with following aggregate:

```
db.consumption.aggregate([
        {$group: {_id:{year:{$year:"$startTime"}}, "Total":{$sum:"$volume"} }}
]);
```

But i also want to sort the result by year.
I want something like below:

```
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2010 }, "Total" : 10 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2011 }, "Total" : 40 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2012 }, "Total" : 5 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2013 }, "Total" : 30.5 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2014 }, "Total" : 484.04999999999995 }
```

I have tried the following but its not working.

```
db.consumption.aggregate([
        {$group: {_id:{year:{$year:"$startTime"}}, "Total":{$sum:"$volume"} }},
        {$sort:  {{$year:"$startTime"}:1} }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aggregate` is pipeline operation, so sort by the output from `group`.

```
db.consumption.aggregate([
        {$group: {_id:{year:{$year:"$startTime"}}, "Total":{$sum:"$volume"} }},
        {$sort:  {"_id.year":1} }
]);
```